# Intranet Development with simple functions

Tags: web, password-protection, intranet, internals

Is my understanding of Intranet = essentially password-protected admin website, with credentials only for registered employees, wrong??

I'm confronted with a task where a client wants to have an intranet with really basic functions (file uploads + file storage on the server is the most "complicated stuff"). I've never developed a so-called intranet so far, and the client already has a website.

What I was actually thinking was just adding an "Intranet" or so link to the existing website, which points to a password - protected subsystem / subdomain, or even a single additional page of the existing site, which in turn represents the intranet.

Ready to go, I consulted some tutorials, blogs and guides about intranets, and wondered why they all speak about you NEEDING an intranet software, like Microsoft SharePoint or whatever. Isn't an intranet developed with these essentially the same as a password-protected administration website? Or am I lacking something here? Of course, softwares come with advantages and ready-to-use stuff, but I've developed quite some login systems for now and feel that it is much easier to develop an intranet with very basic features only as elaborated above on my own, instead of choosing + learning the ideal software. In my opinion, developing one on my own would especially make future edits + adaptations much more convenient..?

Comment: I'm not totally sure what your question is - are you asking us to comment on your opinion?

Comment: No hehe, I'm wondering if intranet software has some MUST - HAVE features which password-protected websites do not have? Why do most forums recommend specialized intranet software, instead of just developing a password-protected website?

Comment: Most intranets have file permissions, versioning, free-text search, notifications for changes, workflows, a forms builder, shared calendars - whole suite of features. You could build all that from scratch, but it's probably cheaper to buy.